# bs4 extract text from multiple spans in a tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract some text from a website using beautiful soup,  the point is that the main div contains multiple tags and some tags have no attributes.

the html looks like:

```
<div class="title">
            <a class="main" href="/vehicles/3563782">
                <span>
                    VAZ
                </span>
                <span class="model">
                    2109
                </span>
                <span class="model-short" style="display: none">
                    2109
                </span>
                <span class="engine">
                    1.5 55kW
                </span>
            </a>
            <span class="tbl-columns">
                <span class="year">
                    1992
                </span>
                <span class="fuel_short_icon">
                    <img class="icon" src="https://img.auto24.ee/images/icons/fuel.png" />
                    P
                </span>
                <span class="transmission_short_icon">
                </span>
                <span class="finance">
                    <span class="pv">
                        <span class="price">
                            €750
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <a class="loan-adv small" href="/vehicles/3563782#loan=72">
                        <span>
                            Monthly payment
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;">
                                €13
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <link href="/styles/modules/a24loan.css?2011101005" rel="stylesheet" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

i want the extracted text to be like: "VAZ 2109 1.5 55kW 1992 €750"

Comment: what happens when you use `goal = list(soup.select_one('.title').stripped_strings)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
goal = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select(
    '.title span:first-child, .model, .engine, .year, .price', limit=5)]
print(*goal)
```

Output:

```
VAZ 2109 1.5 55kW 1992 €750
```

Answer (score 0):

If `html_doc` contains your HTML snippet from the question, you can do:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

title = soup.select_one(".title")

brand = title.span.get_text(strip=True)
model = title.select_one(".model").get_text(strip=True)
engine = title.select_one(".engine").get_text(strip=True)
year = title.select_one(".year").get_text(strip=True)
price = title.select_one(".price").get_text(strip=True)

print(brand, model, engine, year, price)
```

Prints:

```
VAZ 2109 1.5 55kW 1992 €750
```